# How to compare two Pdf files side by side in python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

In my project i am having two folder containning the number of PDF file . Pdf file name are same in both the folder but the text or some other data is different. so i have to compare the pdf file of same name from one folder with the file of other folder and show the difference in them side by side.can u tell the code .

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "difference"? A difference in the text of the PDF or some layout change (e.g. an embedded graphic was resized). The first is easy to detect, the second is almost impossible to get (PDF is an VERY complicated file format, that offers endless file formatting capabilities).

The script below will convert all PDF files in a folder to Text files.

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import os
import sys, getopt

#converts pdf, returns its text content as a string
def convert(fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)

    output = io.StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close
    return text 

#converts all pdfs in directory pdfDir, saves all resulting txt files to txtdir
def convertMultiple(pdfDir, txtDir):
    if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\" #if no pdfDir passed in 
    for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir): #iterate through pdfs in pdf directory
        fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension == "pdf":
            pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
            text = convert(pdfFilename) #get string of text content of pdf
            textFilename = txtDir + pdf + ".txt"
            textFile = open(textFilename, "w") #make text file
            textFile.write(text) #write text to text file

# set paths accordingly:
pdfDir = "C:/your_path/PDF_in/"
txtDir = "C:/your_path/TEXT_out/"
convertMultiple(pdfDir, txtDir)
```

Then, you can do something like this.

```
f1 = open("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Python/PDF Files/Convert All PDF Files to TEXT Files/TEXT_out/file1.pdf.txt")
f2 = open("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Python/PDF Files/Convert All PDF Files to TEXT Files/TEXT_out/file2.pdf.txt")

lines = f2.readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(f1):
    if line != lines[i]:
        print("line", i, "is different:")
        print('\t', line)
        print('\t', lines[i])
```

Comment: Hi bro , I need a to compare crystal reports which are in pdf ,for example online Adobe pdf compare tool is there ,i have to compare two files from two folder and if difference is there then change the colour and show them side by side.